# How can I build a random forest regression model multiple output variables?

Tags: r, regression, multivariate-analysis, python, random-forest

I couldn't find a clear-cut answer for it.

1. 15 input variables, 4 output variables (continuous)
2. 4 output variables are correlated

What kind of random forest model can I implement to do multi-output modeling?

Comment: they are going to say do one variable at a time.  I don't like that because it presumes the covariance is strictly diagonal.

Comment: @EngrStudent I would love to have some direction. Multiple models is easy to do.

Comment: Software-specific questions are off-topic here: please read advice in the Help Center. If you want to revise this question to bring the small purely statistical element in focus, that would be a good idea.

Comment: @maximusdooku - if you move this to StackOverflow (correct forum) then I can show you the (assumption rich, hack) the folks here pointed me to (but they gave no code) when I asked this question.

Comment: @NickCox I have removed all software related queries

Comment: you might ask about how error is handled, and what difference this makes vs. the non-diagonal covariance.  You can also show what you tried that doesn't work, or papers you read through while looking for the answer.  Think of it as staging someone  for a grand-slam of an answer.

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `randomForestSRC` package in R, which supports multivariate regression models. You can look in the help to the `rfsrc` function how to specify the multivariate model:

```
rfsrc(Multivar(y1, y2, ..., yd) ~ . , my.data, ...)
```

The splitting rule is the composite normalized mean-squared error, as you can see in the help. I think it takes into account correlations between dependent variables.

Comment: Thank you. Can you point me to an article or guide that shows how to use that package? The manual is tough to understnd...

Comment: Install the package in R and go to the help file of rfsrc by writting ?rfsrc. This function is well documented. The examples at the bottom also help a lot on how to execute this function.